# talend can not copy project to another workspace

Tags: java, talend

I'm trying to copy my project create in talend v 6.2 to talend v 5.6 and after I keep this error:

> org.talend.commons.exception.LoginException: Cannot open the
>   project.Error task is
>   org.talend.designer.core.generic.model.migration.NewSalesforceMigrationTask.
>     at
>   org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.checkProjectCompatibility(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:287)
>     at
>   org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.logOnProject(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:1779)
>     at
>   org.talend.repository.ui.login.LoginDialog$2.run(LoginDialog.java:366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

Answer (score 0):

There is no backward compatibility, you cannot open a project in 5.6 if it was created in later version.

Answer (score 0):

Talend create a `talend.project` file in every project directory or archive that contains information about the project and the Talend version. This is how Talend protect you from importing project created with newer Talend version.

**You can but its not safe**, replace the `talend.project` in the 6.2 project by another file from a 5.6 project, and you will be able to import the project.